# Rubymine で変更範囲内で grep したい

Tags: git, rubymine, grep

Git で管理しているプロジェクトにおいて、自分の変更した範囲で grep をかけたいです。
コミットを指定するか、あるいはブランチを指定するなどの方法でも良いです。

Rubymine でできれば良いですが、他の方法でも。みなさんどのようにやっているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

#### ターミナル上で調べる

Git 1.7.4 以降で `git log -G<regex> --author=<pattern>` が使えます。

今回の目的だと、以下のオプションが便利でしょう。

- [検索範囲を指定する](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_limiting)

  - `--all`
  - `--branches[=<pattern>]`
  - `--tags[=<pattern>]`
- [コミットの diff を表示する](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_diff_formatting)

  - `-c`： diff を表示する。
  - `--cc`： 短く diff を表示する。

RubyMine を使うなら、RubyMine 上の Terminal を起動してこのコマンドを打ち込むことができます。Terminal は <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> で起動する[検索ウィンドウ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/searching-everywhere.html)から探すか、メニューの "View" → "Tool Windows" → "Terminal" から起動できます。

何回も使うなら、エイリアスを設定すると便利です。

#### その他の Git コマンド

- [`git log -S<string>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log--Sltstringgt)： `-G` オプションと似たオプションです。[`--pickaxe-regex`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---pickaxe-regex)をつけると正規表現にもできます。
- `git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all --author=<pattern>)`： 同じようなことを別のコマンドで行う方法です。これを使うと行単位で出力されます。 (詳しくは [Jeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268330/jeet) さんの [Stack Overflow への投稿](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2929502/5989200)を参照してください)

#### 参考

- ["How to grep (search) committed code in the git history?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2928584/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

  - 上の質問の類似質問たち
  - ["How to grep Git commit diffs or contents for a certain word?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1337320/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
  - ["Is it possible to perform a 'grep search' in all the branches of git project"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15292391/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
  - ["Using git, how could I search for a string across all branches?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7151311/5989200) -- Stack Overflow